# When I run de code the loop continue with the previous question

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to do a text game challenge in python with while loop, but when I finished the game it still continue with the previous question and I want it to stop when the user answer the last question.

```
question = ""


while question.lower() != "yes" and question.lower() != "no":
    question = input("Do you want to play?\n")
    print()
    if question.lower() == "yes":

        while question.lower() != "bottle" and question.lower() != "castle":
            question = input(f"You are alone in a island and you saw a BOTTLE and a CASTLE\n Which one do you choose?\n ")
            print()
            if question.lower() == "bottle":
                                
                while question.lower() != "sea" and question.lower() != "trees":
                    question = input("The bottle has a message: \"No one leaves this island without proving their worth to themselves\", you can try the SEA or the TREES\n Which one do you choose\n")
                    print()
                    if question.lower() == "sea":
                        print("Is already night, and you were ate by a whale \U0001F40B in the blink of an eye")
                        print()
                        break
                    else:
```

....

```
    elif question.lower() == "no":
        print("That´s too bad!")
        print()
    else:
        print("Invalid answer, please try again")
        print()
```

Comment: you want to exit when player answers ```no```?

Comment: It works in the first while loop, when the user answers "no" it stops, but is not the same when the answer is "sea" it comes back the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import sys and use sys.exit() in place of break statements. The code is not working because those break statements breaks only internal while loops not the outer one.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue.